# Can PAM be used with Postfix and Dovecot SASL?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, pam, sasl

I have set up [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) to use [Dovecot SASL](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/authentication_mechanisms/#authentication-authentication-mechanisms) with [PAM](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/pam/) and Unix users, and Dovecot LDA (LMTP) for local mailbox storage. After some testing, turns out incoming mail gets declined with the reason:

> Error: passdb lookup failed for [user]: Configured passdbs don't support credentials lookups

That's both troublesome and troubling - I opted for PAM-based authentication because all sources I found suggested it's the simplest and most reliable way. It's hard for me to troubleshoot what's going wrong at this moment - I'm not sure if it's truly an issue with PAM or if something's wrong with my configuration.

#### Logs

The `doveadm` lookup test:

```
$ doveadm auth lookup [user]
Error: passdb lookup failed for [user]: Configured passdbs don't support credentials lookups
```

Dovecot debug log after the lookup test:

```
$ cat /var/log/dovecot/dovecot-debug.log | tail -5
[date][time] auth: Debug: master in: PASS    1       [user]  service=doveadm debug
[date][time] auth: Debug: pam([user]): Performing passdb lookup
[date][time] auth: Debug: pam([user]): passdb doesn't support credential lookups
[date][time] auth: Debug: pam([user]): Finished passdb lookup
[date][time] auth: Debug: passdb out: FAIL   1       reason=Configured passdbs don't support credentials lookups
```

#### Relevant configuration

The `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` file:

```
auth_username_format = %Ln
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

The `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext` file:

```
passdb {
    driver = pam 
    args = session=yes failure_show_msg=yes dovecot
}
userdb {
    driver = static
    args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%n
}
```

The `/etc/pam.d/dovecot` file is the default that came with the Rocky Linux (that equals RHEL and is the same as Fedora) Dovecot package:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_nologin.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
session    include      password-auth
```

However, I also tried the configuration as suggested by the official [Dovecot PAM documentation](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/pam/#linux) and it didn't yield any different results. I am confident in the rest of my configuration, as I spent considerable time studying the options, but I still barely understand the PAM config...

All logs point at the issue being with the Dovecot SASL itself, not with the Postfix or Dovecot configuration. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: PAM passdb driver just gives you a binary auth *success/failure* result, and your userdb does not help in identifying which users exist. What do you *want* to happen when a message comes in for `nonexistingmailbox@example.org`?

Comment: Preferably the _"Undeliverable mail returned to sender"_ reply, but if I understand it correctly, that is a task for Postfix, not Dovecot. Dovecot just needs to validate whether this user exists on the machine via SASL and return the answer to Postfix. Authentication doesn't happen at this stage - but it needs to work for when users try to read their mailboxes over IMAP/POP3.

Comment: (To be precise, even better: postfix when instructed to `reject_unverified_recipient` learns via LMTP that Dovecot could not find that user, and says so on the incoming connection. The responsibility of generating the return message is then upon the relay of the sender, meaning your setup does not need to generate backscatter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this is the proper solution to the problem (now coming back and reading [anx's comment](https://serverfault.com/q/1098092#comment1432950_1098092) on my original post makes me wonder if it is), but I managed to get both the lookup and authentication working by adding a second `passdb` entry into the Dovecot's configuration.

In the Dovecot configuration, I preceded the [PAM password database](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/pam/) entry with a [*passwd* password database](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/passwd/) entry:

```
# e.g. /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-system.conf.ext
passdb { # This is not a typo
         # Passwd can be used both as a passdb and a userdb
    driver = passwd
}
passdb {
    driver = pam
    args = dovecot
}
```

This makes user lookups with `doveadm auth lookup [user]` succeed. However, the *passwd* database can't *authenticate* users, as the passwords are no longer stored in the `/etc/passwd` file on Unix systems. When that happens, the lookup continues with the PAM password database, which correctly authenticates the user. This can be tested with the `doveadm auth test [user]` command.

---

I added this as an accepted answer, because the solution/workaround currently worked for me. If anyone has any suggestions or knows how this could be solved in a better way, I'm happy to accept it instead. With just the PAM database being the default configuration on [Rocky Linux](https://rockylinux.org/) (practically RHEL), it makes me surprised it wouldn't work out of the box.